# Speakers buzzing and can't seem to find a solution

Tags: audio, speakers, noise

I have Microlab Solo 7C speakers and I've had a lot of problems with buzzing.

I have my computer and projector connected to them and if both the computer and projector are turned off the speakers do a very loud buzzing noise (it can be hear from the other rooms).

I've usually kept my speakers to 50 volume level, but since I connected my projector to them, if I get over 30 they make a very annoying buzzing.

If I get the volume to 30 and increase the PC's volume to compensate they create some kind of echo and I can barely understand voices while watching a movie.

I've been Googling for months now, but I'm unable to find a solution.

UPDATE: I have been trying more stuff and it's really weird. If I disconnect either the projector or PC, the buzzing goes away. I took out the jack from the PC and put it into my smartphone. It's all good, but if I plug my phone charger the buzzing reappears.

Comment: Are both the computer and projector using the same power outlet? If so, separate them. It sounds like power interference to me.

Comment: Yes, they are, because I only have a single one in my room.

Comment: Turn on only one at a time - if the buzzing disappears, I suspect you will have found the problem. The lamp in the projector often sends noise down the line. Let me know, and if that seems to be the case, I can make this an answer and you can accept it. (Unless someone else has a better solution).

Comment: I reread your question, and I see I misunderstood. My "solution" applies to when they are both on - your question says when they are both turned OFF. Is that correct?

Comment: Sounds like you have a bad earth somewhere in one of your power supplies.

Comment: This is the sort of issue than could be solved in 5 minutes flat by simply being there to see it, so much harder to do from a description only. You need to eliminate from the amp back to the sources, one cable at a time, using known-good stock. Check shielding & grounding at each point, then work back to the next device.

Comment: When both the PC and projector are turned off, the buzzing is extremely loud. When one or both of them are turned on, the buzzing is annoying, but not so loud. When I switch the source to the projector, the buzzing gets louder than when it's switched to the PC.

Comment: I have a weird setup. I have 4 cable extenders with multiple sockets in my room. extender 1 comes from the wall plug, extender 2 plugs in it and that's where I have my projector, extender 3 also plugs in 1 and I have the  PC in it, and extended 4 plugs in 3 and I have my speakers in it. I was thinking this could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

If it is power interference, it might help to turn one of the power plugs around (yes, that sounds silly but it helps)

Comment: I really do despair of electrical systems where you can simply turn the mains plug round. Atrocious design, where you can't even rely on a single phase being in-phase.

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 thing I would try,

1) Coil all of the wires, if the speaker wires are unshielded they may be picking up FM interference.

2) If that helps, but does not eliminate it, a Ferite shield will be next (it costs about $1.50)

3) If it is not FM interference, I would try a small UPS to isolate the speakers from inconsistent power, but only after testing the voltage with a true RMS multi meter.  If the voltage is under 110v this can cause the speaker's power supply (especially if it is cheaply made) to oscillate and produce static.

Comment: I'm not really sure how I could coil the wires. Also they're really long: the one that goes to the PC is 3m long, while the other 8m.

And please check my update on the question.

Comment: 8m is a long stretch for an audio input cable on an unbalanced system. You need to be absolutely sure they're shielded.

Comment: On a stretch that long, go straight to the Ferrite Shield, if the wiring is not shielded that is most likely your problem.